# How to add command-line arguments to a Java program launched from Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, jit

I am trying to figure out how to add the command line arguments

```
 -XX:CompileCommand=print,javax/swing/text/GlyphView,getBreakSpot
```

to eclipse in order to fix a JIT problem documented in 
http://kingsfleet.blogspot.com.br/2014/11/but-thats-impossible-or-finding-out.html
but i am unsure how to add this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is part of building as indicated in your question's title then:  You can't.  That is an argument specific to Oracle's javac.  Eclipse's Java Builder uses Eclipse's compiler. If you use ant or any other external tool, to run Oracle's javac then you can add arguments for it.

If this is a runtime option (since you mention the JIT), then you can add any arguments for the JRE in the [Run Configuration](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-java-local-configuration.htm) dialog.

---

I just skimmed the article you referenced.  It is an argument to 'java', not 'javac' and has nothing to do with building.  Enter it in the *Arguments* tab of the [Run Configuration](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-java-local-configuration.htm) dialog.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks I misunderstood the article. Adding it to VM Arguments of the Arguments tab seems to have fixed it.

Comment: do you know if there is a way to suppress the output `CompilerOracle: exclude javax/swing/text/GlyphView.getBreakSpot
### Excluding compile: javax.swing.text.GlyphView::getBreakSpot
`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need "boot time parameters" for your Eclipse, well before the projects are loaded. If I have understood the question correctly, have you tried using eclipse.ini? Here are a few lines from my ini file where I change some parameters.

```
--launcher.appendVmargs$
-vmargs$
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6$
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m$
-Xms40m$
-Xmx1524m$
-Dgrails.console.enable.interactive=false$
-Dgrails.console.enable.terminal=false$
-Djline.terminal=jline.UnsupportedTerminal$
-Dgrails.console.class=grails.build.logging.GrailsEclipseConsole$
```

If I havent' understood your question, please clarify, if not, hope this helps.